# When pressed back button, my app dismiss recent apps

Tags: android, android-activity, back

When my activity is running if the user presses backPressed, the activity is dismissed and it is not visible in the recent apps list. I want it to be shown in the recent apps list. How can I do that?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();

  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
                android:name=".MyActivity"
                android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen
                                      |keyboard|keyboardHidden
                                      |navigation|orientation
                                      |screenLayout|screenSize
                                      |fontScale"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: remove `excludeFromRecents` from manifest

Comment: So when the user presses back you want to dismiss the activity but you want to keep it in the recent-apps list as if the user pressed the home button? In that case, @VivekMishra suggestion looks correct you should not say that you want to exclude it from recent-apps. BTW do you need the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`?

Comment: Yeap I want to show recent app except slide app from recent apps.

Comment: @begiNNer you already got the answer . I just want to confirm are you using [`android:configChanges`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config) intentionally ? If not please See  [Handle configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) and [`android:configChanges`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config).

Comment: @begiNNer it is still not clear what you want to do. You say: "I want to show recent app except slide app from recent apps". Do you want to show the recent-apps list or do you want your app to be listed in the recent apps list?

Comment: I want to show recent apps when user presses back button, but don't show recent apps  when user slides my app from recent apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line form AndroidManifest

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

OR set it false

```
android:excludeFromRecents="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

i think @begiNNer want's to remove the recent application(means last used application) from the device like **CleanMaster** application. So you have to get the **pid** of the running application than remove one by one, If this is the case than the below code will works.

Code:

```
activityManager.killBackgroundProcess(pid);

android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

get pid Code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) 

context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int processid = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
   System.out.println(info.pid);
}
```

Comment: if he wants to remove the application, then excludeFromRecents will do it anyways